# PowerBI compare two columns in matrix

Tags: matrix, powerbi, compare

I am pretty new to PowerBI and cannot figure out a way to compare two values in two columns. All I need is a columns that says True or False. This would be pretty easy in Excel but I am sure there is a way in PowerBI as well?

My data looks like this:

| Number | Type | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PO1 | 5 | 10 |
| PO1 | 6 | 12 |
| PO2 | 5 | 09 |
| PO2 | 6 | 10 |
| PO3 | 5 | 10 |
| PO3 | 6 | 10 |

Which I organise to look like this in a matrix (not exactly this formatting but I don't know how to show this, but it's a matrix):

| Number | Type 5 | Size | Type 6 | Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PO1 | 5 | 10 | 6 | 12 |
| PO2 | 5 | 09 | 6 | 10 |
| PO3 | 5 | 10 | 6 | 10 |

And I want to know:

| Number | Type 5 | Size | Type 6 | Size | Same size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PO1 | 5 | 10 | 6 | 12 | False |
| PO2 | 5 | 09 | 6 | 10 | False |
| PO3 | 5 | 10 | 6 | 10 | True |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this with a calculated table like:

```
Comparison = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Table',
    'Table'[Number],
    "Same size", MIN('Table'[Size]) = MAX('Table'[Size])
)
```

which will look like this in a table visual:

[image]

Comment: This helped me in realising that the min and max values could be used. In the end I ended up grouping the data differently in the Transform Data overview, that solved my problem a bit easier (for now). Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What I did was Transform the data as follows:

- Number as index column
- Min size as 'input'
- Max size as 'output'
- New column comparing input and output

Save and Run